# T-SQL Json_modify function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

T-Sql JSON_MODIFY function has some issue its adding wrapper when appending a new value pair like

```
  declare @jsonstring varchar(max) ='{"Width":"100%","Length":"45%"}'  
  select JSON_MODIFY(@jsonstring,'append $.Height ','50%' )
```

> -- output  {"Width":"100%","Length":"45%","Height":["50%"]}
>    -- Its adding wrapper i am unable to remove that wrapper
>    -- expecting output  {"Width":"100%","Length":"45%","Height":"50%"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query:

```
declare @jsonstring varchar(max) ='{"Width":"100%","Length":"45%"}'  
select JSON_MODIFY(@jsonstring,'$.Height ','50%' )
```

The [documentation for append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says:

*"Optional modifier that specifies that the new value should be appended to the **array** referenced by < json path >."*

Comment: That is it. My idea was to use `JSON_MODIFY` twice [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0039b4c155b5f68bea98cf5b59868ef)